# Python SpeechRecognition to convert speech to text gives wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am trying to learn speech to text for a project and came across this wonderful resource:

https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/

The code example to get audio from a static file is given in the example as:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

print(sr.__version__)

r = sr.Recognizer()

harvard = sr.AudioFile('path_to_audio_file.wav')

with harvard as source:
    audio = r.record(source)

out = r.recognize_google(audio)

print(out)
```

This produces the output as:

> 'the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the
> odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle taste fine with
> ham tacos al Pastore are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross
> bun'

However when I try to run the same code, I get the output as:

> 3.8.1
>
> the salesman old beer drinkers it takes hi to bring out the order I
> call dip restore selfinvest a salt a call this find him because of my
> favourite is just for food is Bihar cross bun

What am I doing worng ? I am not able to figure it out.

**P.S. The same .wav file was used in both the cases.**

Comment: [Edit] your question and show your `print(sr.__version__)`. Try this [examples/audio_transcribe.py](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/audio_transcribe.py)

Comment: @stovfl It is still not working. Tried the example from the link given by you. It still shows the same result :(

Comment: ***"still shows the same result"***: So you can be sure, your code is doing nothing wrong. Have you verified by human that the `..wav` does realy talk the expected words?